# The method emptyIntList() is undefined

Tags: protobuf-java, protocol-buffers

I am new to **Google Protobuf**. Tried to play with it using below **student.proto** file.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package rld;

option java_package = "com.rld";
option java_outer_classname = "StudentDTO";

message Student {
    string name = 1;
    int32 roll = 2;  
    repeated int32 mark = 3; //Marks in various subjects
}

message StudentDatabase {
  repeated Student student = 1;
}
```

Then I tried to compile it using below Protobuf compiler command. From [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.7.0), I downloaded the compiler.

```
protoc -I=. --java_out=. ./student.proto
```

It compiled successfully and generated **StudentDTO.java**, but with errors.
There are two methods '*emptyIntList()*' and '*newIntList()*' used inside the class, but they aren't defined.

Now my question is how to resolve those errors or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being new, it seems I had forgotten to update **Google Protobuf Runtime** while updating **Protobuf Compiler**. Both the versions must match.

Here are 2 solutions.

1. **Maven Users** - Include the following dependency in your **POM** file.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>x.y.z</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. **Non Maven Users** - Include the **protobuf-java-x.y.z.jar** in your classpath.