# Error when trying to perform a synchronous pull on Google pubsub in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to perform a synchronous pull in Java using a Google pubsub subscription, but when I use the documented process (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull) I get an error.

I've been able to perform the same function in Python on the same server and it returns the correct message. So I know the box is ok. Looks like it's an issue with my Java process.

```
  public void readBucket() {
    try {
      List<ReceivedMessage> myMessage = createSubscriberWithSyncPull("my-project", "my-subscription", 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  static List<ReceivedMessage> createSubscriberWithSyncPull(
      String projectId, String subscriptionId, int numOfMessages) throws Exception {
    // [START pubsub_subscriber_sync_pull]
    SubscriberStubSettings subscriberStubSettings =
        SubscriberStubSettings.newBuilder()
            .setTransportChannelProvider(
                SubscriberStubSettings.defaultGrpcTransportProviderBuilder()
                    .setMaxInboundMessageSize(20 << 20) // 20MB
                    .build())
            .build();

    try (SubscriberStub subscriber = GrpcSubscriberStub.create(subscriberStubSettings)) {
      String subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.format(projectId, subscriptionId);
      PullRequest pullRequest =
          PullRequest.newBuilder()
              .setMaxMessages(numOfMessages)
              .setReturnImmediately(true) // return immediately if messages are not available
              .setSubscription(subscriptionName)
              .build();

      // use pullCallable().futureCall to asynchronously perform this operation
      PullResponse pullResponse = subscriber.pullCallable().call(pullRequest);
      List<String> ackIds = new ArrayList<>();
      for (ReceivedMessage message : pullResponse.getReceivedMessagesList()) {
        // handle received message
        // ...
        ackIds.add(message.getAckId());
      }
      // acknowledge received messages
      AcknowledgeRequest acknowledgeRequest =
          AcknowledgeRequest.newBuilder()
              .setSubscription(subscriptionName)
              .addAllAckIds(ackIds)
              .build();
      // use acknowledgeCallable().futureCall to asynchronously perform this operation
      subscriber.acknowledgeCallable().call(acknowledgeRequest);
      return pullResponse.getReceivedMessagesList();
    }
    // [END pubsub_subscriber_sync_pull]
  }
```

I'm pretty certain this is the line causing the problem:

```
SubscriberStub subscriber = GrpcSubscriberStub.create(subscriberStubSettings)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
2019-09-04 15:01:00,727 - ERROR [MapReduceRunner-phase-1:i.c.c.i.a.r.ProgramControllerServiceAdapter$1@97] - MapReduce Program 'phase-1' failed.
java.lang.Exception: com.google.pubsub.v1.StreamingPullRequest.emptyIntList()Lcom/google/protobuf/Internal$IntList;
        at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.lambda$initializeProgram$1(AbstractContext.java:645) ~[na:na]
        at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.execute(AbstractContext.java:600) ~[na:na]
        at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.AbstractContext.initializeProgram(AbstractContext.java:637) ~[na:na]
        at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService.beforeSubmit(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:547) ~[na:na]
        at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService.startUp(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:226) ~[na:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$1.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:47) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.batch.MapReduceRuntimeService$2$1.run(MapReduceRuntimeService.java:450) [na:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.pubsub.v1.StreamingPullRequest.emptyIntList()Lcom/google/protobuf/Internal$IntList;
        at com.google.pubsub.v1.StreamingPullRequest.<init>(StreamingPullRequest.java:30) ~[na:na]
        at com.google.pubsub.v1.StreamingPullRequest.<clinit>(StreamingPullRequest.java:1594) ~[na:na]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.<clinit>(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:149) ~[na:na]
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message looks similar to this other issue: [The method emptyIntList() is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421031/the-method-emptyintlist-is-undefined).

If that's the case, including the `protobuf-java` dependency would fix it if you're using maven.

Comment: Thanks. This was (pretty much) the right answer. Actually in my case the dependency had been included, but it was pointing to an earlier version. Updating this to the latest (3.9.1) fixed the issue.